# How to write right json format

Tags: javascript, json, xml, validation, web

i have json string i want to validate it i use online json format the error show please help me  ": Error: Parse error on line 1:
 {  nodes: {        Creation
----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
my json :"

```
 {
    nodes: {
        Creation: {
            color: 'red',
            shape: 'dot',
            x: 0.4,
            y: 0,
            fixed: true,
            alpha: 1
        },
        Send_To_Modification: {
            color: CLR.branch,
            shape: 'dot',
            x: 0.4,
            y: 0,
            fixed: true,
            alpha: 1
        },
        Send_To_Verification: {
            color: CLR.branch,
            shape: 'dot',
            x: 0.4,
            y: 0,
            fixed: true,
            alpha: 1
        },
        IBAN checking: {
            color: CLR.branch,
            shape: 'dot',
            x: 0.4,
            y: 0,
            fixed: true,
            alpha: 1
        },
        Send_To_Kassip(KWD SAA Down): {
            color: CLR.branch,
            shape: 'dot',
            x: 0.4,
            y: 0,
            fixed: true,
            alpha: 1
        }
    },
    edges: {
        Creation: {
            Send_To_Modification: {
                length: 001
            },
            Send_To_Verification: {
                length: 001
            },
            IBAN checking: {
                length: 001
            },
            Send_To_Kassip(KWD SAA Down): {
                length: 001
            }
        }
    }
 }`
```

Comment: This isn't JSON, but a JS object.

Comment: You could have used any JSON formater online to get your answer instead of asking here.

Comment: Although the site http://json.org is not the newest anymore, it can help you to create a json object.

Answer (score 1):

In JSON, keys must be strings, written with double quotes and string values must also be written with double quotes.

```
{
"nodes": {
    "Creation": {
        "color": "red",
        "shape": "dot",
        "x": 0.4,
        "y": 0,
        "fixed": true,
        "alpha": 1
    },
    "Send_To_Modification": {
        "color": "CLR.branch",
        "shape": "dot",
        "x": 0.4,
        "y": 0,
        "fixed": true,
        "alpha": 1
    },
    "Send_To_Verification": {
        "color": "CLR.branch",
        "shape": "dot",
        "x": 0.4,
        "y": 0,
        "fixed": true,
        "alpha": 1
    },
    "IBAN checking": {
        "color": "CLR.branch",
        "shape": "dot",
        "x": 0.4,
        "y": 0,
        "fixed": true,
        "alpha": 1
    },
    "Send_To_Kassip(KWD SAA Down)": {
        "color": "CLR.branch",
        "shape": "dot",
        "x": 0.4,
        "y": 0,
        "fixed": true,
        "alpha": 1
    }
},
"edges": {
    "Creation": {
        "Send_To_Modification": {
            "length": "001"
        },
        "Send_To_Verification": {
            "length": "001"
        },
        "IBAN checking": {
            "length": "001"
        },
        "Send_To_Kassip(KWD SAA Down)": {
            "length": "001"
        }
      }
   }
}
```